# Python missing value in output of Singly-linked list merge

Tags: python, oop, linked-list, singly-linked-list

Currently I am trying to learn how to merge two singly-linked lists; however, I can't seem to understand why it is missing the first value when I key in the value.

Here are my class..

```
class SinglyListNode:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

class SinglyLinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
```

Here is the merge code I am using:

```
def mergeList(self, list):
    p = self.head 
    q = list.head
    s = None

    if not p:
        return q
    if not q:
        return p

    if p and q:
        if p.data <= q.data:
            s = p 
            p = s.next
        else:
            s = q
            q = s.next
        new_head = s 

    while p and q:
        if p.data <= q.data:
            s.next = p 
            s = p 
            p = s.next
        else:
            s.next = q
            s = q
            q = s.next
    if not p:
        s.next = q 
    if not q:
        s.next = p 
    return new_head
```

These are the numbers in the array

```
  array1 = [ 3, 6, 6, 10, 45, 45, 50] ; 
  array2 = [2, 3, 55, 60 ]
```

And these are the print codes:

```
def printList(self):
    temp = self.head
    print "[",
    while temp is not None:
        print temp.data,
        temp = temp.next
    print "]"

s1.mergeList(s2)
print "Content of merged list"
s1.printList()
```

The output is...

```
[ 3 3 6 6 10 45 45 50 55 60 ]
```

The value 2 in this case does not get printed out.
I have tried to print the value of the head of the new_head in the mergeList and I got a 2.

What I don't understand is why is it that when it is printed, the value of 2 at the head of the list disappears.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm not too sure, but what do you gain by using a SinglyLinkedList over a regular List? I know with normal lists you can do: `combinedList = list1 + list2`.

Comment: It is clearly for education, not production. The gain is the knowledge he gains while implementing the algorithm.

Comment: The input code works - please remove it and replace with `array1 = [ 3, 6, 6, 10, 45, 45, 50] ;  array2 = [2, 3, 55, 60 ]` - add the LinkedList class so this gets a [mcve]. Thanks

Comment: @PatrickArtner Is the root the classes?, I've added them in. Yes, the linkedlist itself is empty at the start and only added after the array codes. From my understanding, wouldn't the linkedlist be inputted with the values of the array based on the merger function? I've cracked my head and really can't figure out why is the value missing from the printed statement. Thanks.

Comment: Add `print(new_head)` before `return` to see your missing `2`. Your `return new_head` is useless, as you don't use it and it don't `return` what you think of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boiling down your code to the important sections, we have:

```
class SinglyLinkedList:
    #...
    def mergeList(self, list):
        p = self.head 
        q = list.head
        s = None

        #...

        if p and q:
            if p.data <= q.data:
                s = p 
                p = s.next
            else:
                s = q
                q = s.next
            new_head = s

            #...

            return new_head

    #...

    s1.mergeList(s2)
    print "Content of merged list"
    s1.printList()
```

While merging the two lists (and as far as I can tell, the logic in this function is correct), you define a variable called `new_head` and then return it.

But then when you call the function with:

```
s1.mergeList(s2)
```

you "throw away" the return value.  But this return value was the head of the merged list, so if the first element of `list` [1], is less than the first element of `self`, printing `s1` will start an element "late".

Instead, consider something like changing:

```
return new_head
```

to

```
self.head = new_head
```

And you will see the list print as you expect.

[1] You might consider a different variable name here, to avoid shadowing the builtin `list` type.

Comment: So does putting self.head = new_head make the first return value the current head value? And why does s1.mergeList(s2) "throw away" the return value? Thank you so much for your answer it worked.

Comment: `self.head = new_head` "updates" the `self` object's `head` attribute (in this case `s1.head`), so that when you call `s1.printList()` it starts at the right spot.  And it "throws it away" because you're not capturing it all (e.g. with something like `new_head = s1.mergeList(s2)`).